# timestamp error while importing datat from csv to postgresql

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, csv, sqlalchemy

```
import uuid
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:xxx@localhost:5432/xxxxa')

df=pd.read_csv("uplauds_corp_financial.csv")
li=[]
for _ in range(len(df)):
    ud = uuid.uuid1()
    print(ud)
    li.append(ud)
df['uuid_']=li
df.to_sql(name="uplauds_corp_financial", con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

ERROR=sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat) invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "23:37.2"
LINE 1: ...75, 140.89, 75.92, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, NULL, '23:37.2',...

maybe it is taking it as string maybe thats why it is showing error 
is there any option that instead of changing it in my csv
i  can change it before importing into postgresql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlimK.jpg)

Comment: It is trying to interpret the time as timestamp but is missing either seconds or hours.
The format should be HH:MM:SS.ms

Comment: @gtomer any way i can edit it ?other than manually doing in my csv

Comment: Pls post part of your CSV so I will be able to help

Comment: @gtomer can i post only this part bcoz main csv is of 196 columns and only 2 rows

Comment: @gtomer is pic visible i'm new sorry

Comment: You can add it as an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you the problem:

```
select '23:37.2'::timestamp;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "23:37.2"
LINE 1: select '23:37.2'::timestamp;

#Reformatting won't help

select '23:37:00.2'::timestamp;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "23:37:00.2"
LINE 1: select '23:37:00.2'::timestamp;


#Use time type

select '23:37.2'::time;
    time    
------------
 00:23:37.2
```

Your data is not providing enough information for use as a timestamp. To be a little clearer you need to change the type for the table field if you are only going to provide a time. Or if you leave it as timestamp then you need to create a complete timestamp(a date and time).